# CS50 RECOVER Looking for a condition statement for iteration

Tags: c, cs50, recover

Hello everyone so this is an CS50 assignment, it supposes to recover a bunch of photos from a memory card by file handling functions of C. It recovers the first photo (that is 000.jpeg) but when it comes to continuing to the new jpeg it can only write one block(512BYTE) once and then stops. I am looking for a condition for it to automate (refering to the above of printf("I can write to the new jpeg\n");) with a while loop but isjpeg() function is not operable since it holds the same beginning (not sure why but tried does not work). I am looking for a way of continuation for it. Thanks all help appreciated.

(This is the output on terminal so that you see the result,Number of I could not found new is reduced for easier demonstration.)

```
$ ./recover card.raw
I could not found a new so keep goin
I could not found a new so keep goin
I can found the first jpeg
I could not found a new so keep goin
I could not found a new so keep goin
I could not found a new so keep goin
I could not found a new so keep goin
I could not found a new so keep goin
I could not found a new so keep goin
I can write to the new jpeg

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int jpegnumber; jpegnumber = 0;
    bool isjpeg();
    bool jpeghasfound = false;
    char filename[8];

    if (argc != 2 )
    {
        printf("Program should have one command line argument \n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (file == NULL)
        return 1;

    BYTE buffer[512];

    FILE* img;

    while (fread(buffer, 512, 1, file)) // if it reads something
    {
        if ( isjpeg(buffer) && (!jpeghasfound) ) // it founds a jpeg first time
        {
            jpeghasfound = true;

            sprintf(filename,"%03i.jpg",jpegnumber);

            img = fopen(filename,"w");
            printf("I can found the first jpeg\n\n");
            if (img == NULL)//nullcheck
            {
                printf("There is nothing to open \n");
                return 1;
            }
            fwrite(buffer,512,1,img);

            jpegnumber++; // increment the count
        }

        else if (isjpeg(buffer) && jpeghasfound)  // Founding a new jpeg
            {
                fclose(file); // close old file
                sprintf(filename,"%03i.jpg",jpegnumber);
                if (img == NULL)//nullcheck
                {
                    printf("There is nothing to open \n");
                    return 1;
                }
                    fwrite(buffer,512,1,img);
                    printf("I can write to the new jpeg\n");
            }
        else  // if we have not find a new jpeg we should keep writing to old file
        {
            fwrite(buffer,512,1,img);
            printf("I could not found a new so keep goin\n");
        }

    }
    fclose(file);
    fclose(img);
}

bool isjpeg(BYTE buffer[])
{

        if((buffer[0] == 0xff ) && (buffer[1] == 0xd8 ) && (buffer[2] == 0xff ) && ((buffer[3] & 0xf0 ) == 0xe0))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
}
```

Comment: Write a little flowchart. You only need one `fwrite` of the data and one test of whether the data is a jpeg header. If it is, you close the file and open another one, and then you write the data. Then all that remains is not to close the one you have not opened, and if you initialise the file pointer with `NULL` that can be your flag.

Comment: You aren't incrementing `jpegnumber` when you start a new file. And you didn't open a new file. And the final `else` should be `else if (jpeghasfound)` since you need to open a file before writing to it.

Comment: I figured out it . Closing the input file was not a smart idea :/ Thanks to you all for your help :)